# image_transport compressed plugin error

Tags: image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When I run image_transport to decompress color images coming from openni I receive this error:

```
rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/camera/rgb/image_color/compressed 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'image_transport::TransportLoadException' what():  Unable to load plugin for transport 'compressed', error string: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class image_transport/compressed_sub with base class type image_transport::SubscriberPlugin does not exist. Declared types are  compressed_sub image_transport/raw_sub theora_sub
```

I see that the *compressed* plugin is installed:

```
rosrun image_transport list_transports 
Declared transports:
compressed
image_transport/raw
theora (*): Not available. Try 'rosmake theora_image_transport'.

Details:
----------
"compressed"
 - Provided by package: compressed_image_transport
 - Publisher: This plugin publishes a CompressedImage using either JPEG or PNG compression.
 - Subscriber: This plugin decompressed a CompressedImage topic.
```

Does any one know why the decompression does not work?

I am using Diamondback...

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9274/image_transport-compressed-plugin-error/) by [Akin](https://answers.ros.org/users/230/akin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2011-03-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was a problem of ROS_PACKAGE_PATH which was bizarrely set to point at another image_transport folder. Setting it to Diamondback solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Akin](https://answers.ros.org/users/230/akin/) with karma: 186 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [grapeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/32370/grapeson/) on 2017-10-31**:
I am definitely coming across with the same problem. Can you tell me more details about how to change the "ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" please? Thanks!